# Reducing the frame rate of an animated GIF in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I'm doing an animated GIF logo for a client and would like to know if there is a way to reduce the frame rate in Photoshop? I know I can delete frames one by one, but that's not a great solution for 30 fps animation. Is there a trick to automatically reduce the frame rate?

Answer (score 2):

Import the animated GIF in Photoshop using File > Import > Video Frames to Layers.

In the dialog box that opens after, you will be able to select the option "Limit To Every x Frames", thus reducing the frame rate and the file size.

http://www.hiadammarshall.com/gif-compression-with-photoshop.html

Comment: Thanks, It worked nicely, Somehow I never paid attention to that option, kept thinking there should be an option during saving.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It seems you can only import video files, not GIFs.